# KineticJS load json layer

Tags: json, kineticjs

I am saving my layers independently to a database. But now I want to load the JSON to the specific layer. But I can only load the JSON for the stage.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic procedure for serializing an individual layer:

```
    var layerJSON=layer.toJSON();
```

Then you can deserialize that layerJSON and add the rehydrated layer to the stage like this:

```
    var layer1=Kinetic.Node.create(layerJSON);
    stage.add(layer1);
    layer1.draw();
```

Remember that images and event handlers are not serialized so you will have to add them to the layers after deserializing.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LMEn6/

Comment: I tried that option and that is no working only if i copy the string and paste it directly to the script then it will work. If it is dynamicly loaded it is not working.

Comment: Then your problem is in either the transport or the database, not in the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: When i add an alert before the create with the json in it. It shows me the correct json. And when i copy this json output in the code it works. So there are no problems with the transport.

Comment: Iam getting an error with the script. Iam using version V5.0.1 and in line 3538 there is an error. (invalid character 9)

Kinetic.Node.create = function(json, container) {
        return this._createNode(JSON.parse(json), container);